Is there a way to disable issues in Xcode Previews failing build?
In Xcode 15, I want to prevent issues in Previews from failing the build. I realise I can comment out the Preview macro or Preview struct, but it would be simpler if there was an option to just disable the behaviour globally i.e. persist the setting across projects.
